# Obscure systemd-logind message on Centos 7 running on OpenVZ 7

Tags: centos7, systemd, openvz, dbus

I am seeing the message below appear several times at random times on a Centos 7 64-bit virtual private server running on OpenVZ 7. I have no idea what it means, how to fix it or if it can be safely ignored. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
Jul  8 11:03:01 server dbus[129]: [system] Connection ":1.6086" (uid=0 pid=13457 comm="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") has had Unix fds pending for too long (pending_fd_timeout=150000ms); tolerating it, because it has uid 0
```

My operating system details are below:

```
# uname -a
Linux server 3.10.0-862.20.2.vz7.73.29 #1 SMP Thu Feb 21 17:35:43 MSK 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

Comment: Does this occur on the host node or in a container?

Comment: This is happening on the container  (i.e. the VPS). I asked my VPS hosting provider about this message and they said they had no clue what it means either.